# Manually computing ideal quotient $\langle x\rangle : \langle x y z \rangle$ in $k[x,y,z,o]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Please explain this ideal quotient in $k[x,y,z,o]$:

$$\langle x\rangle : \langle x y z \rangle=\{f\in k[x,y,z,o] : fg\in \langle x \rangle\quad\forall g\in \langle x y z \rangle \}$$

where

$$fg\in\langle x\rangle \quad\forall g\in\langle xyz\rangle \leftrightarrow fg=Ax\quad \forall q\in \langle xyz\rangle$$

$$f xyz=Bx \leftrightarrow f y z= B \quad\text{(Wrong as observed by Chen)}$$

and my goal is compute manually to the result $\langle x\rangle : \langle x y z \rangle=\langle 1\rangle$.

**Correct result checked with M2**

> "R=QQ[x,y,z,o]; ideal(x):ideal(xyz)" results to "ideal 1" so the whole polynomial ring k[x,y,z,o].

Comment: It seems like the ideal quotient should be all of $R$ - that is, for any ideals $J\subseteq I$, it should be the case that $I:J=R$. Wikipedia has that as one of the properties of the ideal quotient, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient

Comment: Your "correct result checked with M2" is false (I checked it with Macaulay2 too)

Comment: @user26857 can you clarify? I am trying to calculate the quotient as explicitly as possible. Misundenrstood p.194 of Cox et al (Ideals, Varietiens and Algorithms 3rd edition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not right.

The ideal quotient $I \colon J$ is the set of all $r \in R$ such that $rJ \subseteq I$, for $I,J$ ideals of a commutative ring $R$.

Observe that $\langle xyz \rangle \subset \langle x \rangle$ already, so for any $r \in k[x,y,z,o]$, we have that $r\langle xyz \rangle \subseteq \langle xyz \rangle \subseteq \langle x \rangle$ and hence $\langle x \rangle \colon \langle xyz \rangle$ is all of $k[x,y,z,o]$.

Comment: $r\langle xyz\rangle\subseteq\langle x\rangle$ results to $r\langle yz\rangle\subseteq\langle 1\rangle$ but how can the multiplication $r\langle yz\rangle$ be computed to the form $r\in\langle\text{some ideal}\rangle$? +1 for the start :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, it seems like you're "cancelling" the $x$ from both sides. Ideals cannot be manipulated like that however.

Comment: Thank you for the observation, my goal is to learn ideal arithmetics: what does $r\langle xyz\rangle\subseteq\langle x\rangle$ really mean?

Comment: Let $I$ be any ideal in a ring $R$. For $r \in R$, $rI = \{ra \mid a \in I\}$. So $r\langle xyz\rangle$ is the set (ideal, even) of elements $ra$ where $a \in \langle xyz \rangle$. This is necessarily a subring of $\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: What is the operation in $ra$ i.e. between r and a? Is it multiplication? Intersection or how do you understand this notation?

Comment: It's multiplication. I recommend referring to a good algebra text if you want to learn more about ideals in general.

Comment: Is $I:J=\{f\in R : fg \in I \quad\forall g\in J\}$ equivalent to $I:J=\{f\in R \mid fg \in I \quad\forall g\in J\}$? I want to make sure the `":"` outside the curly brackets and `":"` inside the curly brackets have two different meanings.